# pyspark limit number of parallel connections to an API endpoint

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In PySpark, how can I limit the number of parallel connections to an API endpoint?

Let's say I start my PySpark session with 32 executors, however, I want to hit the API with only 8 concurrent connections. How can I do so?

Some sample code:

```
data = [("A", "url1"), ("B", "url2"), ("C", "url3")]
columns = ["col1", "col2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

def api_udf(url):
    response = requests.get(url) 
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return None

api_udf_spark = udf(api_udf, StringType())

# Q. How to limit concurrent connections when applying UDF?
result_df = df.withColumn("api_response", api_udf_spark(df["col2"]))   

result_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: You could create 8 partitions and then use `mapPartitions` instead of the udf to call the api.

Comment: I think @werner meant to say "should" instead of "could"

Comment: @mazaneicha haha!!